# Помогите с компановкой в layout

Tags: java, android

[image: как мне разместить мои разделы на всю высоту экрана,получается чтобы каждый элемент занимал 1/3 высоту экрана]

Как мне разместить мои разделы на всю  высоту экрана? Сейчас получается только так, чтобы каждый элемент занимал 1/3 высоту экрана.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите, например, в сторону атрибута `android:layout_weight`.

В нижеследующем примере каждый из трех `RelativeLayout` занимает по трети экрана.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

*И это, ставьте, пожалуйста, пробелы после знаков препинания.*

Comment: Спасибо  за ответ!